# I want one datepicker to appear in each inputs how?

Tags: jquery

How can i make this other jquery datapicker visable the database insertions don't matter for now but the jquery datepicker does matter i wan't him to be visual. My other code would be in the head section ( scripts and links that are needed ). Please find a fix that works.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12kVm.png)[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSRwv.png)

```
            <div class="form-group row">
                
            
                <div class="col-md-5">                
                <label for="lastdate">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Vom bis :</label>
                <input type="text" id="datepicker"  name="last_date" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('last_date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"  value="{{ old('last_date') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('last_date'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_date') }}</strong>
                </span>
                 @endif
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-2">
               <h2> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;zum </h2>
             </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                <label for="lastdate">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Datum :</label>
                <input type="text" id="datepicker"  name="last_date" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('last_date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"  value="{{ old('last_date') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('last_date'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_date') }}</strong>
                </span>
                 @endif
                </div>

            </div>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script defer src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"  ></script>
   
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
    </script>

        <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
    </script>


    <!-- Fonts -->

    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->

    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontawesome-iconpicker/3.2.0/js/fontawesome-iconpicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.c">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">           

    @include('../templates100100.head100100')
```

Comment: You cannot use same ids . Give different id to your second datepicker and change that inside your jquery code as well.

Comment: Did it and it did not work.

Comment: Working fine check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/krwLpodt/) . Also ,here `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.c">` you have not added `ss` i.e : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: This is it thanks.